# Is there a For...Next loop to jump between web pages to scrape?

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

So I have been trying to scrape info from a site using the code below but am having a tough time with the part I noted. Is there an easier way to get the results I want rather than just repeating the same code over and over? You never know how many results you will get so I cannot use that info.

```
Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
Dim y As Integer
Dim result As String

Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

objIE.Visible = True

objIE.navigate "https://www.searchiqs.com/nyalb/Login.aspx"

Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

objIE.document.getElementById("btnGuestLogin").Click

Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

objIE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtFromDate").Value = "07/01/2017"

objIE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtThruDate").Value = "07/19/2017"

objIE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_cboDocGroup").Value = "DBA"

objIE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_cmdSearch").Click

Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

y = 1

' brings up a table of results. I need to click on the view button and get the info from that page

objIE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_grdResults_btnView_0").Click


Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

' element ID's are hidden for those looking to help

result = Trim(objIE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_lblDetails2").innerText)

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & y).Value = result

y = y + 1

' I would love to direct link to the next serch result here but the link does not change between pages so I click the next button

objIE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_btnNext").Click

Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

result = Trim(objIE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_lblDetails2").innerText)

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & y).Value = result

y = y + 1

' and I click the next button again

objIE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_btnNext").Click

Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

result = Trim(objIE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_lblDetails2").innerText)

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & y).Value = result

y = y + 1

'AND AGAIN

objIE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_btnNext").Click

Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
result = Trim(objIE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_lblDetails2").innerText)

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & y).Value = result

y = y + 1

' You get the idea

objIE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_btnNext").Click
Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

result = Trim(objIE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_lblDetails2").innerText)

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & y).Value = result

' I basically repeat that process til I cant press CTRL V anymore. Is there a loop I can use to tighten this up?
```

Let me know. You guys have been a huge help in the past. Also would it be beneficial to use the XML method as my readystate loops have been giving me issues? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So basically, you're clicking "Next" until the webpage itself no longer shows the "Next" button, correct?  That's how you know when to stop?

Comment: Use a for loop and check whether getElementById returns `Nothing` to determine whether the button exists or not.

Comment: Yes BruceWayne that is correct except the next button just becomes hidden. It wont return a "nothing" value at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, a For loop for the required number of iterations if it's a static set of pages.  I believe we can make it simpler.

```
For y = 1 to 5
    result =trim(objIE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_lblDetails2").innerText)
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & y).Value = result
    objIE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_btnNext").Click
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
next y
'or if you want it to keep going, something like this
Do until objIE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_btnNext") is nothing
    result =trim(objIE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_lblDetails2").innerText)
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & y).Value = result
        objIE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_btnNext").Click
        Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
loop
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I used this and have fixed THIS problem. I used the second code as I do not ever know the exact number of loops I will need. The problem is that my next button never returns a value of "nothing" so it continues to run script until I manually stop it, which is fine. I was wondering if you had a solution for that possibility? The button just fades at the end. I can put it in another question if you wish.

Comment: Glad to help.  Ah I believe if it fades out on the last click, it may be there but not visible?  You can set a condition before the `next` to see if it's not visible anymore